# Get next and last ISO week number in a year

Tags: python, datetime

By this I am getting current week number

```
datetime.date(2014, 9, 30).isocalendar()[1]
```

but I want to get what is next ISO week number and max ISO week number in current year in python.

I can't add current week number + 1 to get next week number, because it may be that year doesn't have that week number.

Comment: And so far you've tried... what, exactly?

Comment: Just look at the documentation for the time module.

Comment: @jonrsharpe and @ Newb i dont think my ques is similar to those ques.

Comment: @KapilJain Then edit your post and explain your question in more detail. You gave a one sentence description and "Please help", which is not a question. Show expected input, output, and what you've tried to code so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get next week's week number, add a `timedelta`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date(2014, 9, 30)
>>> next_week = today + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
>>> next_week.isocalendar()[1]
41
```

To get the last week number in the year, note that the [following rule](http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/ISO_week_date) is used:

> The following years have 53 weeks:
>
> - years starting with Thursday
> - leap years starting with Wednesday